# Why does PyImport_ImportModule return a NULL object type and not nullptr?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-c-api

I am trying to convert code that was written using PyRun_SimpleString to code using the C API more robustly.

I've noticed some unusual behaviour in my code.

1) Py_GetVersion() returns a different version than PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "version") after modififing the version attribute with PyObject_SetAttrString()

2) The module "sympy" which exists in the folder
       C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
doesn't seem to load successfully.  However, the PyObject is not a nullptr.
The sympy module has been confirmed to work correctly in the python command line.

3) The module "not a real module" which does not exist returns nullptr.

4) the PyPyObjects sys_path and folder_path, when viewed with MSVS2015 in break mode, have weird object types.   sys_path is obj_type "\x3" and folder_path is "unable to read memory".  I've noticed that other PyObjects also seem to have non-sense object types but work as expected.  My best guess is that the pointer to the object type is null and returning random memory which is then attempted to be converted to a string.  By why when then do the PyObjects work as expected?

So why does PyImport_ImportModule return a null object type for the "sympy" module but a nullptr for "not a real module"?  Is this undefined behaviour, an issue with MSVS2015, issue with python 3.x etc.?

ANY advice is greatly appreciated as I've hit a wall on this issue.

The code snippet below retruns:

> ```
>    python
>    [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35
>
>
>    3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>    3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32    bit (Intel)]
>    3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>
>
>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\python35.zip
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\Lib
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\DLLs
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\pythonIO\Debug
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\lib\site-packages
>
>
>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\python35.zip
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\Lib
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\DLLs
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\pythonIO\Debug
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35
>    C:\Users\ch816\Dropbox (Personal)\expressionParser\python35\lib\site-packages
>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
> ```

```
Py_Initialize();

std::cout << ws2s(Py_GetProgramName()) << "\n";
std::cout << std::string(Py_GetCompiler()) << "\n";
std::cout << ws2s(Py_GetExecPrefix()) << "\n";
std::cout << "\n\n";

PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");

std::cout << std::string(Py_GetVersion()) << "\n";

PyObject_SetAttrString(
    sys, 
    "version", 
    PyUnicode_FromString("3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 
bit (Intel)]")
);

std::cout << std::string(Py_GetVersion()) << "\n";
std::cout << PyObj2String(PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "version")) << "\n";
std::cout << "\n\n";

PyObject* sys_path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
for (auto& p : PyList2Vec(sys_path)) {
    std::cout << p << "\n";
}

std::cout << "\n\n";

PyObject* folder_path = PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages");
PyList_Append(sys_path, folder_path);

for (auto& p : PyList2Vec(sys_path)) {
    std::cout << p << "\n";
}

PyObject* pSympyMod = PyImport_ImportModule("sympy");
PyObject* pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pSympyMod);
PyObject* symbolsFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pSympyMod, "symbols");
PyObject* pNotaMod = PyImport_ImportModule("not a real module");
```

Comment: Why are you setting attr string of version?

Comment: The anaconda install adds text into sys.version that PyRun can't parse with regex parser.  Removing '|Continuum Analytics, Inc.|' fixes this.